# Append the String using StringBuilder

Tags: java, android, string, android-spinner, stringbuilder

I am trying to get all the items that I have selected in Spinner using the layout. I am creating the Spinner dynamically and adding the items to Spinner dynamically so that is the reason I am using layout here to get the `ChildElement`.

Below is the code:-

```
int count = layout.getChildCount();

StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();

View v = null;
int j = 1;
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    v = layout.getChildAt(i);

    if(v instanceof Spinner) {
        jsonString.append("["+j+":"+((Spinner) v).getSelectedItem()+"]");

        j++;
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

It's a simple String Manipulation problem.

I have `5 Spinner` currently. So I am trying to make `jsonString` like this.

```
[1:CS,2:EE,3:RE,4:TT,5:UU]
```

Here `CS,EE,RE,TT,UU` are the items that I have selected in my `5 Spinner`

But with my code, my `jsonString` is getting shown like this-

```
[1:CS][2:EE][3:RE][4:TT][5:UU]
```

How can I make the `jsonString` like the way I wanted. I am sure, the way I am using append is not correct.

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you write the code above? Because if you don't want the closing brackets, you shouldn't add them explicitly. In either case, the "json" you're attempting to produce isn't valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems very simple. You've put '[' and ']' within the loop in append which is appending square brackets at each iteration. Try the following (I haven't tested it.)

```
    int count = layout.getChildCount();

    StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();

    View v = null;
    int j = 1;
    jsonString.append("[");
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        v = layout.getChildAt(i);

        if(v instanceof Spinner) {
            jsonString.append(j+":"+((Spinner) v).getSelectedItem());

        if (j != count) //if this is not the last spinner
            jsonString.append(",");
        j++;
        }
    }
    jsonString.append("]");
```